# Ajax delete returns 200 but firing off error event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have read through loads of posted threads and none seem to deal with delete.
My code is returning a 200 status yet fires of the error event...

```
            $.ajax({
             type: 'DELETE',
             url: '/' + type + '/' + name,
             success: function() {
                 window.alert(type + " " + name + " successful");
             },
             error: function(xhr, status) {
                 alert(xhr.status);
                 alert('Failed to delete ' + type + ' ' + name)
             }
            });
```

Comment: Debug `error` method and check on `xhr` for the complete error description. It will be clear for you then what's wrong

Comment: are you returning some data in the response?

Comment: Well this is the complete object that gets returned ---- {"readyState":4,"responseText":"","status":200,"statusText":"OK"}. What confuses me is why would the error event get fired

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that there was no dataType defined. I added dataType: 'text' and I resolved my problem.

Comment: Got the same and your trick fixed it. Although this does not seem right, as no content is being passed nor returned...

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because of `type: 'DELETE'`. Change it to `type: 'JSON'` or remove it at all. Since you are returning wrongly formatted response, you get error callback fired. Safe if you specify `json` type and echo anything besides of json string.

Comment: `type` in `$.ajax()`  refers to http method used (`GET,POST,PUT,DELETE`).

Comment: @LIUFA In docs, there is mentioned, that DELETE and PUT may be not supported by browser, so it might be making problems