# Ajax delete request returns 200 but fires error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, http-delete

I am trying to create a simple API for my project. I am sending a DELETE request using jquery Ajax. The Delete request gets sent, does what it is supposed to do(deletes an entry from the database), return a status 200, but fires an error event.

I have already looked for solutions on these posts but they haven't been able to help me:

[Ajax request returns 200 but error event is fired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43006935/ajax-request-returns-200-but-error-event-is-fired)
[Ajax request returns 200 OK but error event is fired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64701066/ajax-request-returns-200-ok-but-error-event-is-fired)
[Ajax delete returns 200 but firing off error event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24452736/ajax-delete-returns-200-but-firing-off-error-event)

This is the AJAX code:

```
        function ajaxCall(method,hmm){ // function that send an ajax request
            $.ajax({
                dataType: 'JSON',
                url: '/APIHandler.php?' + $.param({values:hmm}),
                type: method,
                success: function(response) { // when the request is done delete the previously placed products for new ones
                    console.log(response);
                    const parentDiv = document.querySelector('#basic-grid');
                    removeAllChildNodes(parentDiv);
                    turnToObjects(response);
                },
                error: function(xhr){
                    alert(xhr);
                    console.log(xhr);
                }
              });
        }
...
ajaxCall('DELETE',checked);
```

The APIHandler code:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'DELETE') {
    $vals = $_GET['values'];
    $API->delete($vals);
}
```

The request response:

```
abort: ƒ (e)
arguments: [Exception: TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them at Function.r (<anonymous>:1:83)]
caller: [Exception: TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them at Function.r (<anonymous>:1:83)]
length: 1
name: "abort"
prototype: {constructor: ƒ}
__proto__: ƒ ()
[[FunctionLocation]]: jquery.min.js:2
[[Scopes]]: Scopes[3]
always: ƒ ()
catch: ƒ (e)
done: ƒ ()
fail: ƒ ()
getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ ()
getResponseHeader: ƒ (e)
overrideMimeType: ƒ (e)
pipe: ƒ ()
progress: ƒ ()
promise: ƒ (e)
readyState: 4
responseText: ""
setRequestHeader: ƒ (e,t)
state: ƒ ()
status: 200
statusCode: ƒ (e)
statusText: "OK"
then: ƒ (t,n,r)
```

I also can't find any solutions for the error

```
[Exception: TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them at Function.r (<anonymous>:1:83)]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `contentType:'application/json'` to your code

And change `dataType` to `text`

```
...
dataType: 'text',
contentType:'application/json'
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You set your `dataType` as `JSON` so $.ajax is attempting to parse your ajax response as JSON but your response is empty so an error is thrown.
Either send a JSON response from your request or remove the `dataType` parameter.